# Tree search algorithm to find optimal terminal node

Tags: graph-traversal

I have a few board games where in each round one can do a set of action. Depending on the previous actions, the set of possible actions is different. Usually after a fixed amount of rounds, the game is finished and one computes the total number of points.

One such game is Nidavellir ([draft blog post](http://martin-ueding.de/posts/nidavellir-coins/index.html)), where one plays eight rounds. The player has effectively has four integer-valued coins, starting with 2, 3, 4 and 5. In each round one can choose two of these, and the higher valued one gets replaced with the sum of the two set aside. The maximum value of a coin is 25. The final score is the sum of all coins.

Using a full breadth-first tree traversal I can iterate through these $6^8 = 1\,679\,616$ ways to play the game and find the winning strategy. It yields 58 points and each step has the following coins:

- 2, 3, 4, 5
- 2, 3, 5, 7
- 2, 5, 5, 7
- 2, 5, 7, 10
- 2, 7, 7, 10
- 2, 7, 10, 14
- 2, 7, 10, 24
- 2, 7, 17, 24
- 2, 7, 24, 25

There are other games where the complexity is rather in the order of $20^{30}$, so a full traversal doesn't work. Therefore I want to gather experience with algorithms that can traverse the tree a bit more efficiently.

In both cases I have tried *beam search*. In the Nidavellir case and with a beam size of 100, the best solution found only scores 55 points. The problem likely is that long-term benefits don't get accounted for properly. This is even more pronounced with Scythe, where the player has to spend resources (short-term loss) to gain achievements (long-term gain). The beam search, at least when used with the current end-game-score as a weight, doesn't perform so well there.

I have tried to use Q-learning, but I have a hard time modelling the Q-function for such a huge graph problem. For Scythe not all the actions are possible in each step, I am not sure how to model that sensibly.

Are there some other algorithms for this type of problem, where one can iteratively explore a huge graph and improve on solutions?

Comment: 58=58? $ \quad $

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks for the pointers! A* doesn't feel applicable, as I don't know the terminal node, nor the distance. Monte Carlo tree search is promising, though its application doesn't seem trivial when there is no win/loss/draw outcome, but points. I still need an evaluation function. But it fares much better when using the current points and finds the optimal solution after exploring 33,000 of 1,100,000 possible final states.

Comment: A* doesn't require that you know the distance.  It requires that you construct an admissible heuristic.  It doesn't require that there be a single terminal node.  It does require you be able to identify which nodes are terminal, but that is easy in your case: each node should capture the full state of the game, which in your case includes the number of rounds remaining, and then every node with 0 rounds remaining is terminal.  I think  A* might be worth another look.